# Audio player in excerpt wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm trying to display the audio player in the post excerpt in Wordpress. On [this](https://benrobertson.io/wordpress/allow-audio-in-wordpress-excerpt) website I found the following code that I added to functions.php:

```
/**
  * Create an excerpt that includes the audio for podcasts.
  * @return string The excerpt HTML
  */
 function wp_podcast_excerpt() {

     // Gets the post content
     $content = get_the_content();

     // Find the position of the audio shortcode in the content
     $audiopos = strpos($content,'[audio');

     if($audiopos) {

         // The excerpt is all the text up to and including the audio tag.
         $excerpt = substr($content, 0, strpos($content,'[/audio]'));

         // Apply wordpress filters.
         $excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt);

         // Strip out images.
         $excerpt = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $excerpt);

         echo $excerpt;

     } else {
         the_excerpt();
     }
 }
```

In the loop I have included:

```
<?php wp_podcast_excerpt(); ?>
```

This only shows the text and nothing else. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment:

> The excerpt is all the text up to and including the audio tag.

Is incorrect. At that point in time, `$excerpt` contains the text up to, but *excluding* the closing audio tag. I'd imagine you'd like to have this included in `$excerpt`, so that it is properly parsed by WordPress filters.

You could do all manor of things to ensure that it's included when applying filters. One very straight-forward way would be to increase `substr`s third parameter by an amount that equals the length of the string `[/audio]`:

```
$closing_audio_tag = '[/audio]';

// The excerpt is all the text up to and including the audio tag.
$excerpt = substr(
    $content,
    0,
    strpos($content, $closing_audio_tag) + strlen($closing_audio_tag)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm trying to apply this to the existing code by changing it, adding it... but with no result. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I got the result I wanted. Here is the solutions.

Add this to the functions.php:

```
<?php add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode'); ?>
```

Then, inside the loop add:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[audio]"); ?>
```

All together it look like this:

```
    <?php

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <?php the_title() ?>

            <?php the_excerpt() ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode("[audio]"); ?>
        
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```